Use ASCII to display math (no ASCII math) from latex
In the early days of the internet, it was recommended to use ASCII to in email to
represent mathematical formula (see for example
http://accounts.smccd.edu/churchg/m120ww/ascii_examples.html
Does anybody know about a converter (best online) that would translate latex formula in these sort of
ASCII expressions for example
\int e^{2α t} dx
To

 /
|  2\alpha t
| e         dx
|
/

Rationale. I need to write math formula in an ISSUE system that does not support images or anything fancy.
Thanks
Uwe Brauer

I used to have (probably still do, somewhere) some xslt to generate that sort of thing from mathml, but I wouldnt use it these days. If you need an ascii only version \int e^{2\alpha t} dx is just far more readable than the ascii-art version, so while it may look cute, generating the 2D ASCII display is self defeating in the end.

here https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/main/pmathmlascii/pmathmlascii.xsl

Does the system support Unicode? In that case you can try to write the expressions inline, something like ∫e^2αt dx.

Take a look at sympy, a Python package : https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html .

the system supports unicode, I found out that in Ubuntu there is pari-gp that includes tex2mail, which seems to do what I want (well wanted, David Charlisle is may be right, the result will be distorted easily. I will look into sympy
